# How to use regex in mysql query to remove specific characters?

Tags: mysql, regex, case

In my query I am using `REPLACE( b.DESCRIPTION,'SP. Z O.O.','') AS DESCRIPTION` to remove `SP. Z O.O.` these characters from columns. And hopefully it's working for me. But in my database `SP. Z O.O.` this characters are stored in different ways. Like `sp. Z.o.o`, `SP. z.o.o` etc.
Somewhere it's stored in capital letters  and somewhere it's stored in small letters.
`REPLACE( b.DESCRIPTION,'SP. Z O.O.','') AS DESCRIPTION` by this method I am only able to remove capital letters. I want all conditions to remove similar words like this.
How to apply regex or case in this situation?

This is my query:

> SELECT b.TRANS_DETAILS_ID, b.CREDIT_AMOUNT, b.ENTITY_NAME, REPLACE( b.DESCRIPTION,'SP. Z O.O.','') AS DESCRIPTION, DATE_FORMAT(a.TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME,'%d-%m-%Y') AS TRANS_DATE FROM bank_book_transaction_master a, bank_book_transaction_details b WHERE a.TRANSACTION_DATE_TIME BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-26' AND DEBIT_CREDIT_FLAG = 1 AND a.ORG_ID = '53' AND a.BANK_ID = '14' AND a.TRANSACTION_ID = b.TRANS_MASTER_ID

Comment: is there just one `SP. Z...` in description to remove, or possibly more than one in a given description?

Comment: is what's between the Z and the first O really sometimes a space and sometimes a `.`?  or is that just a mistake in your examples?

Comment: What collation are you using?  Perhaps `..._ci` will do the case-folding you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a query like this:

```
UPDATE strtest
 SET mystring = CONCAT( 
         LEFT (mystring, POSITION('SP. Z O.O.' IN  mystring)-1),
         RIGHT(mystring, LENGTH(mystring)-POSITION('SP. Z O.O.' IN  mystring)-9)
         )
WHERE mystring LIKE '%SP. Z O.O.%';
```

**Sample:**

Test Table

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from strtest;
+----+------------------+
| id | mystring         |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | SP. Z O.O.       |
|  2 | ABCSP. Z O.O.    |
|  3 | SP. Z O.O.XYZ    |
|  4 | QWESP. Z O.O.IOP |
|  5 | AAASp. Z o.O.LLL |
+----+------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Remove the String in a SELECT ( The >>><<< are only for test)

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT CONCAT( '>>>',
    ->            LEFT (mystring, POSITION('SP. Z O.O.' IN  mystring)-1),
    ->          RIGHT(mystring, LENGTH(mystring)-POSITION('SP. Z O.O.' IN  mystring)-9),
    ->          '<<<') AS resultstring
    ->        FROM strtest;
+--------------+
| resultstring |
+--------------+
| >>><<<       |
| >>>ABC<<<    |
| >>>XYZ<<<    |
| >>>QWEIOP<<< |
| >>>AAALLL<<< |
+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To UPDATE the Table

```
MariaDB [bernd]> UPDATE strtest
    ->  SET mystring = CONCAT(
    ->            LEFT (mystring, POSITION('SP. Z O.O.' IN  mystring)-1),
    ->          RIGHT(mystring, LENGTH(mystring)-POSITION('SP. Z O.O.' IN  mystring)-9)
    ->          )
    -> WHERE mystring LIKE '%SP. Z O.O.%';
Query OK, 5 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 5  Changed: 5  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT * from strtest;
+----+----------+
| id | mystring |
+----+----------+
|  1 |          |
|  2 | ABC      |
|  3 | XYZ      |
|  4 | QWEIOP   |
|  5 | AAALLL   |
+----+----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MariaDB, you could use REGEXP_REPLACE() like the next line:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(col, regexp, replace)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql) you will find examples about the usage.

Comment: Beware of the wildcard nature of `.`.